# how to get token from firebase auth

Tags: flutter

I need to get token from firebase when i do auth and then transfer token to backend.I have several cases auth.I have not worked with token yet.What should i do for next step?

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() => _firebaseAuth.currentUser();

  Future<AuthResult> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final authentication = await GoogleAuth().signIn();
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: authentication.accessToken,
      idToken: authentication.idToken,
    );
    return _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

Future<AuthResult> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) {
    return _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
final UserCredential authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final token = authResult.credential.token;
```